# How to set a custom route source in openvpn

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn, linux-networking

I have a simple openvpn configuration.

```
remote 1.2.3.4
dev tun
ifconfig 10.74.1.13 10.75.2.1
secret static.key
route 10.75.0.0 255.255.0.0
keepalive 10 60
```

When the link come up, the routing table is updated.

```
[me@localhost ~]$ ip route
10.75.2.1 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.74.1.13
10.21.54.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.21.54.133
10.74.0.0/16 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.74.0.13
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  scope link  metric 1004
**10.75.0.0/16 via 10.75.2.1 dev tun0**
default via 10.21.54.2 dev eth0
```

When the packets arrive at the other end (10.75.2.1) the source ip address is 10.74.1.13.  But I want the source address to be 10.74.0.13.  I can run this command

```
[me@localhost ~]$ sudo ip route change 10.75.0.0/16 via 10.75.2.1 src 10.74.0.13
```

to make this change.  Now the source address is what I want it to be (10.74.0.13).  The last part of the puzzle is what my question is all about.

**How can I get OpenVPN to set the route up this way when the link is first established?**

Comment: Your vpn server should have a "push route ..." statement in the configfile so that the client's route is set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get access to my server. But I remember that you can make a custom `ifconfig` or `route` config file for every PC that make a connection to the VPN server.

Comment: Right.  openvpn has the --up option.  I'll check it out.

Comment: Maybe you could show/explain how to do this?

Comment: The parameter `route-up` seems to work.  Rather than spec the route w/ `route 10.75.0.0 255.255.0.0`, I used `route-up "/sbin/ip route add 10.75.0.0/16 via 10.75.2.1 src 10.74.0.13"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about openvpn but pptpd allows you to store your user accounts an a mysql database and specify a framed ip address for each user when using the freeradius-mysql plugin for pptpd.

Here is a configuration tutorial:

http://www.pmoghadam.com/homepage/HTML/slackware-12.2-poptop-freeradius-mysql-pppoe-server.html

Comment: Wow.  I had no idea that pptpd allow such flexibility.  Thank for the link!